# Can't login into the CocoonJS Developer app

Tags: cocoonjs

I want to log in into the CocoonJS Developer app (on iOS, iPad mini), but I got an error "CSRF protection". I aso tried "Connect with Google", but that isn't working either because of cookie settings or something.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I also tried it on my iPhone 4S, but also without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, but now it just says unknown error. Maybe it doesnt like jailbroken iphones/ipads

another possibility (and the cause of my issue) is you're using the old cacoonjs app on your ipad mini.  It's confusing because they left links to get that app on the appstore on their old website which is still online here: https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/

You have to now go to cacoon.io and follow instructions, the old services are no longer running. https://cocoon.io/